# pandas create extra columns in dataframe from other dataframe by multiindex

Tags: python, pandas

I have two pandas dataframes with the same column names, and same (two) multi-index columns ('symbol' and 'date') but some of the indices are different and some of the data is different.

```
df1 index columns: ['symbol','date']
symbol  date     o    c
aa      2015/1/1 1    1
aa      2015/2/1 2    2
bb      2015/1/1 71   71

df2 index columns: ['symbol','date']

symbol  date     o    c
aa      2015/1/1 1    1
bb      2016/2/1 2    2
bb      2015/1/1 51   55
```

I first want to create a shared dataframe with only the lines in both (an innerjoin with the default `dataframe.merge()` and keep only the index columns. Is there any way to do that in one shot?

Currently I do it the hard way:

```
merged = df1.merge(df2)  
analyzed = merged[['symbol','date']].copy
```

Now comes the question:

I want to have the analyzed dataframe with the following columns: o1 c1 o2 c2
with the data from the two files. how do I ".loc" to get the data by index?

I want something like the following code, but that gives an exception:

```
analyzed['o1'] = analyzed.apply(lambda row: df1['o'].loc[[row.symbol, row.date]]
# or maybe like this: 
analyzed['o1'] = analyzed.apply(lambda row: df1.at[ [row['symbol'], row['date']], 'o'] )
```

How do I do this? Or (in another way to ask) how do I get the current row's symbol and date values, and how do I use them to set the corresponding row in df1 (or df2)? Perhaps something with get_level_values? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC:

### Using join:

```
analyze = df1.join(df2,lsuffix='_l')
```

Output:

```
                 o_l  c_l     o     c
symbol date                          
aa     2015/1/1    1    1   1.0   1.0
       2015/2/1    2    2   NaN   NaN
bb     2015/1/1   71   71  51.0  55.0
```

Selection:

```
analyze.loc[('aa','2015/1/1')]

o_l    1.0
c_l    1.0
o      1.0
c      1.0
Name: (aa, 2015/1/1), dtype: float64
```

### Using merge with indexes:

```
analyze1 = df1.merge(df2, left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

Output:

```
                 o_x  c_x  o_y  c_y
symbol date                        
aa     2015/1/1    1    1    1    1
bb     2015/1/1   71   71   51   55
```

Selection:

```
analyze1.loc[('aa','2015/1/1')]

o_x    1
c_x    1
o_y    1
c_y    1
Name: (aa, 2015/1/1), dtype: int64
```

Comment: Wow thanks. So I accomplish the analyzed. Now I can do the lambdas with the data in the analyzed row, never searching for info in the other dataframe. 

From your code I also understood that if I would (wrongly) wish to use a lambda I would get to the df1 column of that index with: `analyzed['o1'] = analyzed.apply(
    lambda row: df1['o'].loc[(row['symbol'], row['date'])])` 

but that doesn't work. (Syntax error). How do I get the certain column from the .loc[(indexcol1, indexcol2)]

Comment: I also tried `analyzed['o1'] = analyzed.apply( lambda row: df1.loc[(row['symbol'], row['date']), 'open'])`
according to these docs https://www.shanelynn.ie/select-pandas-dataframe-rows-and-columns-using-iloc-loc-and-ix/  but I get an error

Comment: @pashute You don't need apply and lambdas.  You just need to use .loc[rowindex, colindex].  Since your rowindex is multiindex, it looks a bit strange analyze.loc[('aa','2015/1/1'),['o_x','o_y']), the first argument is a tuple for the multiindex, the second argument is list for two columns.

Comment: Thanks @Scott_Boston !  That explains it. The first a tuple, the second a list. And I understood already that once I have the join, there is no need for apply nor lambda. I can set `analyzed['o_indicator'] = analyzed.['o_x'] / analyzed.['o_y'] - 1`

Comment: BUT.....  IF I do wish to use an apply for some reason, I wanted to know how. So now I know how. Instead of the example code from my previous comment, I would use: `analyzed['o_new']  = analyzed.apply(lambda row: df1.loc[(row['symbol'], row['datetime']),['o']].value `  so `df1.loc` would receive a tuple (with values from the row), and then a list with a single column's name, to retrieve the single value of that row...   A bad and useless example, but shows how to use the df1.loc inside apply with lambda that depends on a different dataset.